# calculate total number of guesses in number guessing game ruby

Tags: ruby

To calculate $totalNoOfGuesses you would add $noOfGuesses together from each game played, correct? How do I execute that in my code? I've tried several different options, but it doesn't work. Am I supposed to be creating an array or something?

```
def play_game
    $noOfGuesses=0 
    $gameCount+=1

number = generate_number  

loop do
  print "\nEnter your guess and press the Enter key: "
  reply = STDIN.gets  
  reply.chop!         
  reply = reply.to_i  
    $noOfGuesses+=1
```

Between this would be if reply > or <, too high or too low...  reply = get.to_i

```
  $noOfGuesses=0   
  $gameCount=0   
  $totalNoOfGuesses=0 
  $avgNoOfGuesses=0 

  answer = ""

  loop do

  Console_Screen.cls  
  print "Are you ready to play the Ruby Number Guessing Game? (y/n): "

  answer = STDIN.gets  
  answer.chop!  

  break if answer == "y" || answer == "n" 

  end 

  if answer == "n"  
  Console_Screen.cls  
  puts "Okay, perhaps another time.\n\n"

  else  

   loop do

   SQ.play_game

   Console_Screen.cls  

    print "It took you #{$noOfGuesses} attempt#{'s' if $noOfGuesses > 1}.\n"
    print "You have played #{$gameCount} time#{'s' if $gameCount > 1}.\n"
    print "It has taken you #{$totalNoOfGuesses} attempts in #{$gameCount} game#{'s' if $gameCount >1}.\n\n"
```

Comment: Have a think about which points in your program you should be resetting `$noOfGuesses` to 0.. and when you might want to increase or reset `$totalNoOfGuesses`.

Comment: When doing Ruby try not to use global variables so casually. `$` has very particular meaning in Ruby unlike other languages such as PHP or Perl.

Comment: Well that was easier than I had made it out to be! I was thinking that there was something more to it. Thanks.

Comment: @tadman I thought that I was using the global variable too much. Which type of variable should I be using in this case? Class? Instance?

Comment: If you're wrapping this up inside a class, `@`-style instance variables are the way to go *if* you need to preserve values between method calls. In this case you can use regular local variables, no `$` or `@` prefix is necessary. Globals should be used very, very sparingly. For example, I've written untold thousands of lines of Ruby code and have never been forced to go down that road yet, there's usually a better way to do it. Might seem like a minor quibble, but globals cause surprises, and surprises are usually bad.

Comment: ok, awesome. Thanks so much!